# ¿Cómo buscar un atributo especifico en un arreglo de objetos? Java

Tags: java

Soy principiante en esto de la programación y estoy tratando de buscar, en un arreglo de objetos, cual objeto tiene un atributo en especifico.

Tengo un arreglo de objetos llamado Colaboradores, con objetos llamados colaborador llenando sus espacios. Necesito leer el arreglo y comparar si el atributo código(ingresado por el usuario del sistema), está en alguno de los objetos colaborador; si este si está, dejar acceder a un método, y si no esta, devolver a la pantalla de inicio.

Agradezco su ayuda!

```
package proyectolimpio;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Colaborador {

    int codigo;
    String Nombre;
    String Apellido;
    int Cedula;
    int NumeroTelefono;

    public Colaborador() {

    }

    public int getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

    public void setCodigo(int codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return Nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String Nombre) {
        this.Nombre = Nombre;
    }

    public String getApellido() {
        return Apellido;
    }

    public void setApellido(String Apellido) {
        this.Apellido = Apellido;
    }

    public int getCedula() {
        return Cedula;
    }

    public void setCedula(int Cedula) {
        this.Cedula = Cedula;
    }

    public int getNumeroTelefono() {
        return NumeroTelefono;
    }

    public void setNumeroTelefono(int NumeroTelefono) {
        this.NumeroTelefono = NumeroTelefono;
    }

}


public void DefinirColaborador(){

        Colaborador k = new Colaborador();
        k.setNombre(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Digite su nombre: " , "Datos de colaboradores", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE));
        k.setApellido(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Digite su apellido: " , "Datos de colaboradores", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE));
        k.setCedula(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Digite su numero de cedula: " , "Datos de colaboradores", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE)));
        k.setNumeroTelefono(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Digite su numero de telefono:" , "Datos de colaboradores", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE)));
        k.setCodigo(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Digite su código: " , "Datos de colaboradores", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE)));

        AlmacenColaboradores(k);

 public void AlmacenColaboradores(Colaborador colaborador){ //metodo que almacena los colaboradores, variable tipo colaborador.

        Colaborador colaboradores[] = new Colaborador[2];
        int x;
        for(x=0;x<colaboradores.length;x++){
        colaboradores[x] = colaborador;

       }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para conseguir lo que comentas puedes crear un bucle para acceder al arreglo. Dentro del bucle comparar el código que quieres encontrar con cada uno de los códigos de los colaboradores:

```
codigoQueBusco == colaboradores[x].getCodigo();
```

Espero te ayude.